# Consulta SQL Server com LIKE

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, servidor, tabela-banco-de-dados

Quando rodo o script abaixo no meu SQL Server:

```
SELECT [PTV_CODIGO],[TVC_SEQUENCIAL],[PTV_EIXO],[PTV_PESO_MAXIMO],[PTV_DATA], 
[PTV_NUMERO_EIXOS],[PTV_EIXO_GRUPO] 
FROM [GUARDIANTAG2].[dbo].[tbPesoEixoTipoVeiculo]
```

Obtenho a saida abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando rodo o scipt abaixo:

```
SELECT [PTV_CODIGO],[TVC_SEQUENCIAL],[PTV_EIXO],[PTV_PESO_MAXIMO],[PTV_DATA], 
FROM [GUARDIANTAG2].[dbo].[tbPesoEixoTipoVeiculo] 
WHERE [PTV_CODIGO] = 109
```

Obtenho a saída abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Porém, quando rodo o script abaixo:**

```
SELECT [PTV_CODIGO],[TVC_SEQUENCIAL],[PTV_EIXO],[PTV_PESO_MAXIMO],[PTV_DATA], 
[PTV_NUMERO_EIXOS],[PTV_EIXO_GRUPO] 
FROM [GUARDIANTAG2].[dbo].[tbPesoEixoTipoVeiculo] 
WHERE [PTV_DATA] LIKE '2014-01-17%'
```

Não obtenho retorno algum, conforme imagem a seguir
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo as propriedades da tabela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Gostaria de entender porque não está retornando nada no meu LIKE***

Comment: LIKE é algo que se utiliza para campos texto. Para funcionar para um campo datetime, teria que fazer um CONVERT para varchar, e isso não é prático. Para isso que você quer, você pode usar DATEPART, mas me parece mais prático usar BETWEEN

Comment: SELECT [PTV_CODIGO],[TVC_SEQUENCIAL],[PTV_EIXO],[PTV_PESO_MAXIMO],
[PTV_DATA],[PTV_NUMERO_EIXOS],[PTV_EIXO_GRUPO] 


FROM [GUARDIANTAG2].[dbo].[tbPesoEixoTipoVeiculo] 


WHERE [PTV_DATA] BETWEEN '2022-09-20' AND '2022-09-22'

Obtive:
Mensagem 242, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 2
A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.

Comment: Pela mensagem o formato de datas configurado no servidor deve estar diferente de yyyy-mm-dd. Se você quer obter todas as linhas de um determinado dia pode experimentar `WHERE [PTV_DATA] BETWEEN '20140117 00:00:00.000000' AND '20140117 23:59:59.9999999'` OU `WHERE [PTV_DATA] >= '20140117' AND [PTV_DATA] < '20140118'` OU `WHERE CAST([PTV_DATA] AS DATE) = '20140117'`

Answer (score -2):

O campo PTV_DATA deve estar no formato DATE ou DATETIME. Se estiver, use:

```
where CONVERT(DATE,PTV_DATA,120) between '2022-09-01' and '2022-09-30'
```

ou...

```
where CONVERT(DATE,PTV_DATA,120)='2022-09-30'
```